# html preload "as" attribute for videos

Tags: html, video, preload

I'm trying to figure out what is the right way to use preload for videos.

There is a lot of crossed information on the web about using the **preload attribute** for videos. W3C indicated that i should use **as="video"** when preloading but i also found other information indicating i should us **as="media"** for videos.

Which one is the correct attribute between the two?

[here's the link](https://w3c.github.io/preload/#as-attribute) showing W3C statement.

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation there is nothing related to as="media", only thing mentioned about media is this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content#Including_media where is specified that you can preload certain elements(image/video/etc) for certain media queries. The list is very clear and does not target any general media.

Comment: Thanks Dinca, Nevertheless, lots of blog posts on the web mention the use of media. Even my IDE mark video as a wrong value..

Comment: I don't want to argue you, but what is written in "Smashing Magazine" or other blogs with the `as="media"` is not present in official documentation.Find a working example an try it out, but that won't guarantee the support/compatibility offered by W3C.